# Why do we use the average-pooling layers instead of max-pooling layers in the DenseNet?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In the paper of DenseNet. The author adopted average-pooling in the transition layers. So what is the motivation of such choice? Why not using max-pooling layers?

Answer (score 1):

Average pooling can better represent the overall strength of a feature by passing gradients through all indices(while gradient flows through only the max index in max pooling), which is very like the DenseNet itself that connections are built between any two layers.